# Array returning same values for all indexes

Tags: c#, arrays

I created an object called Participant.
Now I want to have an array of my Participant objects so that I could show them in a datagrid.

Here are the codes I tried (for better understanding of the problem, I removed the loops and datagrid codes):

```
Participant[] list = new Participant[count];
Participant one = new Participant(name, address);
Participant two = new Participant(name2, address2);

list[0] = one;
list[1] = two;
```

However, when I get values of one participant like through a messagebox in this manner,

```
MessageBox.Show(list[0].getName());
```

all it reflects are the data of participant two. Same is true if I have 3 objects, all it reflects is the data last sent into the array.

I know it is possible to have array of objects so there must be something I'm doing wrong. Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think you might want to actually show some of your looping code, my take is that your problem is there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the code as presented, the only way I can think of causing that is if the backig field (in `Participant`) was declared "`static`". If so, remove the "`static`".

Otherwise; does the actual code do a "`new`" for the two objects? Or does it overwrite an object after adding it to the array? (which means you have the same object twice in the array).

I would expect `ReferenceEquals(list[0], list[1])` to be false in a sane world - can you test this and let us know?

Final thought; is there a "`foreach`" in the real code? It could be the [infamous captured variable problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/closures/)...

Comment: I wonder, without seeing the code. How come you can discuss so much ? Do you have any error encylopedia :]

Comment: @Marc Gravell: No problem. I'm surprised that the iPod lacks the backtick; the iPhone doesn't (when entering text, press and hold the apostrophe key and a list of other symbols including the backtick comes up). See tip #2 here: http://mashable.com/2010/08/19/iphone-keyboard-shortcuts-tips-tricks/. Used it many times myself when unable to break the addition and must answer or comment while on train or in car or in grocery store or on a date or.... Ugh.

Comment: @Marc Gravell- That's a lot of Talent. I am astonished by your c# knowledge.

Comment: Didn't know my object classes are full of "static" variables. This solved my problems. :D Thank you so much!!

Comment: @iamnobody - "static" is per-type; so an over-abundance of static variables is usually an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a loop to populate your array, be sure you use the loop index as the index of the array when you assign the paticipant.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging is an underrated skill...  Set a breakpoint on the line where you create the array and add list as a watch, and expand it so you see the contents.  Step through your code and hover over the parameters as you're creating the Participants to see the values being passed.  Step over the statemens that add them to the list and verify in your watch that the correct item and values are in the array each time and that the existing values haven't changed.

Comment: Debugging has been my best friend during programming. Been doing it for quite a while now with this code, it just didn't occur to me that the variables were set as static. Thanks anyways! :)